# binding windows form controls to sql server data in c#

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

i have combobox bound to datasource. i did this through combobox properties. i also textbox bound to same datasource. when try to change the item in combobox then it changes the value in textbox. but when i try to select another item from combobox then it gives error "
 "This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same property.
Parameter name: binding"

this is the code for binding textbox

```
        private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from ProductMaster", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "ProductMaster");

        textBox5.DataBindings.Add("text", ds, "ProductMaster.Rate");

        label17.DataBindings.Add("text", ds, "ProductMaster.VAT");
        con.Close();
    }
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

You should clear your Binding each time. because every time that you select a new item in your combo Box this event binds the data source to combo and since it has been bound before(with your previous selected item) it gives the error . exactly the same problem happened to me yesterday and I solved by clearing the Bindings each time before new binding.

this is my code:

```
 private void cmb_aye_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      OleDbDataAdapter da_select = new OleDbDataAdapter(string.Format("SELECT * FROM quran WHERE (sure={0} and aye={1})", cmb_sure.SelectedItem.ToString(), cmb_aye.SelectedItem.ToString()), objConnection);
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      dt.Clear();
      da_select.Fill(dt);
      txt_tarjome.DataBindings.Clear();
      txt_tarjome.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "tarjome");
      txt_matn_aye.DataBindings.Clear();
      txt_matn_aye.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "baerab");
    }
```